# How to calculate close and high-low deltas of a stocks/cryptocurrencies in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, data-science

I am working on volatility of stocks and cryptos. My goal is calculating their historical high/low and close deltas.

In mathematically the formula of close delta is: (1 - close price/previous close price) and high/low delta formula is: (Difference between High and Low / Previous Close Price)

I want to merge result in one dataframe. I tried below:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    df['Closedelta'] = (1 - df['Close'].iloc[i] / df['Close'].iloc[i-1])
```

With this code I am getting same result for every row, [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89pf4.png).

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the df['Closedelta'] in the for loop you are setting 1 value for the entire column, you should specify the row aswell to which you want to connect the value to.

Change `df['Closedelta']` to `df.iloc[i,5]`

Comment: Thank you @stijn but I just could not understand your way. Why am I changing `df['Closedelta']`? I want to delta values in "Closedelta" column and I do not understand `df.iloc[i,5]` part.